# Updating console/logs in-app. I don't really know how to explain it

Tags: swift

I need something, a box, where it updates with new text.
I don't really know how to explain it, if you play the game A Dark Room on iOS, it's the console thing on the left.  It updates with new text, and you can scroll up and down with it to find previous text (overflow on it I guess.). I'm terrible at explaining. Sorry.
I was thinking about making a list view controller but I don't know how to use it. I'll look it up, though.

Comment: Can you give background on what exactly you are trying to do and try to clarify your question. Your question is how to make a list view controller? Or is your question "how can I make a console control in my application with similar functionality to the one in A Dark Room for iOS"? Can you give a screenshot of this to clarify? I can't answer BTW but I think you could improve the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only about logs, like if you want to show text body with few paragraphs, you can use textView. Whenever you have new text you can append it to current text in textview and update textview again. Whenever required, user can scroll up and look at the previous text.
[image]

Comment: I wanted to do this but it appends it to the top, and you would scroll down to view previous messages. 
Would I be able to do that? I also need each message to disappear every 30 seconds or so after it's created.

Comment: This totally depends on how you manipulate your data. Whenever ou receive a new data, append it after your existing data using NSSTring conveniences. UITextView is subclasses from UIScrollView, so you can take help of scrollview methods also to scroll automatically to the newly added text.